# Similarities between algorithms in anomaly detection in time series

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

I am interested in detecting outliers (contextual outliers, global outliers) in a 2-dimensional time series data, so I decided to use the tsoutliers library implemented in R, Holt method (I could not use Holt-Winter because the period is not fixed) and DBSCAN. Holt method and tsoutliers were applied separately to each variable, while DBSCAN was applied to the 2-dimensional time series. Tsoutliers was applied to the original data, Holt's method was applied after removing seasonality with dummies and DBSCAN was applied to the residuals of an ARIMA model after removing seasonality and trend.
I used the Jaccard index to measure the similarity between the three algorithms and obtained a very low similarity between the algorithms.
The similarities are shown in the figure below. Is this a normal result and if not, what could be the cause of this problem? (I used DBSCAN on residuals because otherwise the algorithm would only be able to find global outliers)[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where the idea is from to use DBSCAN. This is not designed to find time series outliers (I see what you did to apply it but still wonder whether this is proposed with some evaluation and/or theory for this setting anywhere). In any case it will look for clusters and then declare outliers what doesn't belong to any cluster, which is really quite different from what I believe the other methods do (although I'm not expert enough for them to write an answer). Also DBSCAN depends on choices of the tuning constants.

Comment: I've read many research papers applying DBSCAN  to time series. Anyway, How can the Jaccard index  between the Holt method and the Hyndman method be so small?

Comment: Have you verified that any of the methods give reasonable results? Could be that they are all near random but with different biases...

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details on how the similarity between methods has been computed?